# Ember-cli build failed: no such file or directory

Tags: ember-cli, build-error

I migrate my grunt project to ember-cli project, after resolving all JSHint errors, I run "ember build", but got the following error output:

```
    version: 0.2.3
BuildingBuilding.Building..Building...BuildingBuilding.Building..Building...Build failed.
ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\work\mi\kiford\tmp\funnel-dest_j2vQCU.tmp'
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\work\mi\kiford\tmp\funnel-dest_j2vQCU.tmp'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:761:18)
    at D:\work\mi\kiford\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-merge-trees\index.js:32:21
    at Array.map (native)
    at mergeRelativePath (D:\work\mi\kiford\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-merge-trees\index.js:30:29)
    at D:\work\mi\kiford\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-merge-trees\index.js:23:5
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (D:\work\mi\kiford\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:489:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (D:\work\mi\kiford\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:501:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (D:\work\mi\kiford\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:472:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (D:\work\mi\kiford\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1290:9)
```

Any clue to fix it?

Comment: Did you npm & bower install ?

Comment: After run npm&bower install, the error became:'ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\work\mi\kiford\tmp\tree_merger-tmp_dest_di
r-CqLb3eD5.tmp\app\styles''

Comment: Ok, after styles is added to /app, building  succeeds

Comment: Nice, glad you got it working :D